# Magento product page variables

Tags: php, magento, variables, product

I'm running Magento CE 1.9 and I have a piece of code that displays the sku on the product page:
template > catalog > product > view.phtml

the php code is:
     < ?php echo $this->getProduct()->getSku() ?>

which works perfectly, but if I try to add the sku somewhere else in the page... such as for a piece of code for PowerReviews where it needs the SKU to be dynamically inserted for tracking... if I add the same php code to get the sku, it breaks the page right there. I am not sure why I can display the sku in the view.phtml, but not in a product page tab for example...

in this example, I need it in a custom tab I made... so it would be: frontend/rwd/default/template/so/reviews.phtml

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show the sku?

Comment: It is displaying in view.phtml because view.phtml uses catalog/category_view block. when $this->getProduct() is called the product instance will be created and using that we can getSku(). If you write the same code in somewhere else $this will not be having the access to call the getSku function. Where exactly do you want to show the sku?

Comment: in this example, I need it in a custom tab I made... so it would be: frontend/rwd/default/template/so/reviews.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is understanding how Magento blocks are defined. Templates, like `app/design/frontend/[DESIGN PACKAGE]/[THEME]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`, have a corresponding PHP block definition. This specific template, for example, has its block defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php`--and you should even see that this is commented at the top of the core template file for the product view block:

```
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
```

Inside the block definition, you should find a method called `getProduct` which is why you can access that method from the `view.phtml` block. The `$this` variable refers to an instance of the block definition object, so an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`, in other words. If the other block definitions (including those from third-party libraries) where you wish to access the product do not define a method like `getProduct` (or inherit from a block definition that does), then you will not be able to call that method and return a product. What you *can* do, is define a similar method on the block definition for whatever block you want to use to access product data. As an example, you could copy the `getProduct` method definition from the core product view block definition into the block definition for the block from your PowerReviews extension.

This resource should give you a decent overview and hopefully a better understanding of the concept:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates

**UPDATE:** Here's a bit more direction and some elaboration on my reply in the comments. One way to tackle this is to use an existing block definition for your block in the layout definition, like so:

You could choose to use an existing block definition for your template file, or you could create your own (and possibly inherit that class)

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="my.product.block" template="path/to/custom/template.pthml" />
```

Notice I'm using the Magento core `catalog/product_view` block type which corresponds to the PHP file I mentioned previously that defines the block and its `getProduct` method.

Or if you need some kind of custom functionality in your block but you want to rely on the base functionality of an existing block, define your own block and extend an existing one that has the desired functionality:

```
class MyPackage_MyExtension_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View {
    // add your custom methods
}
```

Here I'm extending the existing Magento core block definition that has the method you want. Then use your custom block definition in the layout definition:

```
<block type="mypackage_myextension/product_view" name="my.product.block" template="path/to/custom/template.pthml" />
```

Hopefully that helps clear it up a bit more.

Comment: ok, I'm going to mess with this a little bit and see what I can come up with! I appreciate it, there isnt an extension surprisingly for PowerReviews, which is why I am coding it in manually... which would be easy if I could get the sku variable! :) which this looks to get me in the right direction... thank you (so for my new tab I made, which has a phtml file, do I need to also make a php block for it, so I can paste in the product instance like the other guy commented above?

Comment: Yes, OR you could make your template definition rely on an existing block definition. However, it would need to be one that already includes the method to retrieve the SKU data.